# qpen's setbrush method parameter doesn't match documentation

Tags: c++, qt

I am building a c++ app with Qt5.  In the examples of QPen I see that I can set the brush as follows:

```
QPen* myPen = new QPen();
myPen->setBrush(Qt::cyan);
```

While this compiles fine, it doesn't match the documentation.  QPen's setBrush method is supposed to receive a QBrush.  Why is it acceptable to pass in a Qt::GlobalColor instead?  From the QPen.h file it does not appear that setBrush is overloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QBrush` has a conversion constructor for `Qt::GlobalColor`, i.e. compiler can use it to convert a `Qt::GlobarColor` to `QBrush`.

Here is its definition in `qbrush.h`:

```
QBrush(Qt::GlobalColor color, Qt::BrushStyle style = Qt::SolidPattern)
```

This constructor is, what's been called in your `myPen->setBrush(Qt::cyan);` function call to create a `QBrush` for you and pass to `setBrush()`.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean/121163#121163) to learn more about the conversion constructor concept.